# How to know which manager has deleted a Youtube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, youtube-live

My educational institution has a Youtube channel, it is a branded account. Some 30 teachers are connected to the channel as managers to upload their class videos, some are also using the live feature. But now, someone is deleting all the videos. Is there any way to know who is doing it or can I make it unable for them to delete videos?